# JavaToWS Error: java.lang.AbstractMethodError generating a webservice from classes

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, java2wsdl

I'm trying to generate a wsdl file from Java classes using Eclipse Oxigen
*(Right Click on  class -> WebService -> Create Web Service)*, Java 8u152 runtime and Tomcat 7.

With the following settings:

- Web Service type: Bottom up Java Bean Web Service Service
- Implementation: my concrete class
- Slider:Develop service
- Runtime: CXF 2.x
- SEI: my interface class

I have fed Eclipse with the CXF 3.2.2 jar (the same happens with 2.2.9 and 2.3.1).

I get the following error:

```
JavaToWS Error: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
    at org.apache.cxf.helpers.DOMUtils.getDocumentBuilder(DOMUtils.java:108)
    at org.apache.cxf.helpers.DOMUtils.createDocument(DOMUtils.java:148)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.read(StaxUtils.java:1181)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.read(StaxUtils.java:1178)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.read(StaxUtils.java:1139)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.dom.ExtendedDocumentBuilder.parse(ExtendedDocumentBuilder.java:100)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolSpec.<init>(ToolSpec.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:58)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:40)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWS.run(JavaToWS.java:78)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWS.main(JavaToWS.java:46)
```

And it does not generate anything but an unwanted cxf-beans.xml.

Am I missing something?

Comment: it throws AbstractMethodError there is probably a conflict or differentiate version from one of your jar file.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible exists a problem with "xml-apis" or "xmlParserAPIs" on the classpath

you due to verify your version for it has the method `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(String )`.

For example, the first version with method in xml-apis is 1.4.01

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was caused by xerces jar which was included in the classpath. I searched for it in Dependency Hierarchy of pom.xml and I have removed the artifact for xerces jar.

```
<exclusion>
       <groupId>batik</groupId>
       <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
 </exclusion>
```